# Get character from string between similar sings

Tags: java, android, string, substring

I am trying to get a path of an image in my android device, such as:

> / storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/NAME.jpg

and just trying to grab the image name, but i can.

I am trying with ...

```
String s = imagePath;
```

Where the route imagePath

```
s = s.substring (s.indexOf ("/") + 1); 
s.substring s = (0, s.indexOf () "."); 
Log.e ("image name", s);
```

it returns me :

> storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/NAME.jpg

and i only want

> NAME.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `String.lastIndexOf()`:

```
String imagePath = "/path/to/file/here/file.jpg";
String path = imagePath.substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks! after 10 minutes i gif you the Accepted Answer! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

```
File imgFile = new File(imagePath);
String filename = imgFile.getFilename();
```

This saves you a lot of hassle when you want to use your application cross-platform, because on Linux you have "/" as path delimiters and "\" on Windows

Answer (score 0):

In case, if you are dealing with `File` object, then you can use its predefined method `getName()`.

i.e.:

```
    File mFile = new File("path of file");
    String filename = mFile.getName();
```